# Springboot: ScriptUtils does not seed data in H2 when beans are injected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a working springboot application. At startup it executes a sql script to seed some test data in the H2 database. I just used this and it worked fine so far.

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:portalDB;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
    hikari:
      pool-name: springHikariCP
      connection-timeout: 30000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      minimum-idle: 2
    data:
        - file:../data.sql
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

When I change the application implementing something like this: [Spring Security hasPermission for Collection<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251325/spring-security-haspermission-for-collectionobject/44981329#44981329)

The sql script is not executed.

I found out that the the issue starts with this code:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
                new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        // Pay attention here, or Spring will not be able to resolve bean
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

Then injection of `PermissionEvaluator` triggers the injection of a number of cascading dependencies.
The last component in the chain has 2 dependencies. When any of the two is injected `data.sql` is not executed.

If I remove both dependencies, `data.sql` is correctly executed.

From what I can see `ScriptUtils` is not picking up the files somehow.
I wonder how could the two things related.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve by breaking circular dependencies in Bean injection which seems to cause this issue.

Something around these lines:

```java
@Component
class MyPermissionEvaluator implement PermissionEvaluator 
{
  @Autowired
  ObjectFactory<MyPermissionEvaluator> factory;

  public MyPermissionEvaluator {
     return factory.getObject();
  }
}
```